# Changing Selenium driver for new URL

Tags: python, python-2.7, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I used Selenium to navigate to a URL (i.e. URL_1) with a login/password and provided the login credentials.  I'm logged in and the URL (i.e. URL_2) has changed as expected.  I don't know how to navigate URL_2 because the driver still refers to URL_1.

Thanks in advance.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

user_name = 'xyz'
password = 'xyz'

def login_process():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("URL_1") 
    #successfully navigated to URL_1

    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
    elem.clear()
    elem.send_keys(user_name)

    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    elem.clear()
    elem.send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
    #successfully entered URL_2 

def query():
    HOW DO I CHANGE THE DRIVER TO URL_2?

    #elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name(ticker_box) #this doesn't work, references URL_1 driver
    #elem.clear()
    #elem.send_keys('xyz')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of having independent functions, *create a class* with driver instance as an *instance variable*. Then, use `self.driver.get()` to navigate to a different URL:

```
class MyTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def login_process(self):
        self.driver.get("URL_1") 
        #successfully navigated to URL_1

        elem = self.driver.find_element_by_name("username")
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys(user_name)

        elem = self.driver.find_element_by_name("password")
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys(password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
        #successfully entered URL_2 

    def query(self):
        self.driver.get("URL2")
        # do smth

test = MyTest()
test.login_process()
test.query()
```

Comment: I'm a total beginner and still learning about classes.  I'm getting the same 'NameError: global name 'driver' is not defined (as above) when running the script as a class.  I'm trying to work through that now, but would appreciate any additional thoughts.

Comment: @ac2001 you just have the `driver` variable left somewhere. Now we operate the driver instance variable which should be referred as `self.driver` inside the instance methods.

Comment: that worked, thank you.  I will have to spend more time getting a handle of classes.

Answer (score 2):

After navigating to the new page if you want to do something on that new page

```
newURl = driver.window_handles[0]

driver.switch_to.window(newURl)
```

After doing this you can do something in the new url without getting "no such element exceptions"

Answer (score 0):

First you can assign the url variable as a global:

```
global url;
url = "firstURL"
```

At the end of your first function you can change the value of the variable to the new URL:

```
url = driver.current_url
```

And then you can get the new url at the beginning of your second function:

```
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. I'm getting a 'NameError: global name 'driver' is not defined.  I had tried a couple solutions myself and encountered similar errors.

Comment: Ah yes, the variable was local to your first function, and that's why the second function couldn't see it. I edited my response above. :)